# Optimize query in Laravel Backpack n-n relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4, laravel-backpack

I am building a backend panel for a website with Laravel Backpack. It is really nice, but I have noticed that relationship queries are very expensive.

I have two models: **Product** and **Center** with a many to many relationship between them. In my CenterCrudController I have defined a field this way:

```
$this->crud->addColumns([
    // More fields...
    [      
        'label' => 'Products',
        'type' => 'select2_multiple',
        'name' => 'products', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'entity' => 'products', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model' => 'App\Models\Product', // foreign key model
        'pivot' => true, // on create&update, do you need to add/delete pivot table entries?
     ],
     // More fields...
]);
```

It works fine, showing a select multiple field with related models. But the query used is `SELECT * FROM products`, which is highly expensive (table products have thousands of records with about 25 columns).

In this example I only need *id* and *name* fields. I am looking for something like Query Builder `select()` method.

Is there a way for optimizing this type of query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you tried to select it using get?

 ->get(['id','name'])

Comment: @AshishPatel: thank you, but I can't figure out how to use that. Method `CrudPanel::get()` doesn't exists. Can you explain it, please?

Comment: I think [the select2_from_ajax field](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#section-select2_from_ajax) is perfect for you.

Comment: @tabacitu: that is exactly what I finally did. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is actually an answer, but I'll post it anyway.

The best solution (as pointed by @tabacitu) was using `select2_from_ajax field`. It doesn't slow page load and make an ajax request for retrieving data only when user clicks on the select field.